# Hide arguments of commands in Proced

Tags: proced

Is there any way to hide arguments of commands in `proced`? By default it shows processes like:

```
/usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
```

I want it to be more readable by just showing `/usr/bin/dbus-daemon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proced` uses the function `proced-format-args` to manipulate process string (column: `Args`).

To have a different output you can replace it with your own function. For example this one:

```
(defun proced-format-args-names-only (a)
    (prin1 (car (split-string a))))
```

After you defined the function you need to tell proced to use it. This can be done with:

1. M-x `customize-variable` RET `proced-grammar-alist` RET.
2. Then search for the Attribute with `Key: args`
3. and replace the `Formatting Function: proced-format-args` with the one you defined (i.e. `proced-format-args-names-only`).
4. apply/save your customization
5. and do `M-x proced`.